# Quick Crosswalk For State Abbreviations & State Names

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

For the millionth time I had a dataset today that listed full state names. But, I needed it to list state postal code abbreviations. Here is a code snip I wrote that mapped the changes for me using data from a generic website.

1) Anyone know of or think of a better solution?

2a) Anyone know of a better web reference? Using USPS sites (such as the ones below) will not seem to work with `pd.read_html()`

2b) I also had a hard time isolating the correct table from `pd.read_html()` and the wiki page at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._state_abbreviations

```py
import pandas as pd


# Make Generic Data For Demonstration Purpose
data = {'StName':['Wisconsin','Minnesota','Minnesota',
                     'Wisconsin','Florida','New York']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Get State Crosswalk From Generic Website
crosswalk = 'http://app02.clerk.org/menu/ccis/Help/CCIS%20Codes/state_codes.html'
states = pd.read_html(crosswalk)[0]

# Demo Crosswalking State Name to State Abbreviation
df['StAbbr'] = df['StName'].map(dict(zip(states['Description'], 
                                         states['Code'])))

# Demo Reverse Crosswalking Back to State Name
df['StNameAgain'] = df['StName'].map(dict(zip(states['Code'], 
                                              states['Description'])))
```

Comment: you could get more fine tuning with beautifulsoup. did you try it?

Comment: Interesting idea. Could you post an example of what you might think would work?